# combine 2 query statements into one

Tags: sql

hi I have 2 sql query and I would like to run it in one query
so to explain about the query the first one to get the most frequent brand names

then the second one to get the most item sold with empty brand name column

now I want to combine both so I can get the list of products where they have empty brand name column but the name of product contains the list of brands I have

here is my 2 query

```
select brand_name as top_brands
 from "catalog-my"."catalog_my_20210425" 
 where store_merchant_id like '%lazada%' and brand_name in ( 'HP'     ,'Acer','VAKIND','Casio','Lenovo','BF1 Soul',
                                                          'Sony','Lenovo','Samsung','Bosch','Xiaomi',
                                                       'Panasonic','Dell','Rondaful','Toshiba','UCUC',
                                                       'zanzea','CAMERON SINO','ZZOOI','Canon',
                                                      'Philips','LEGO','Glamorousky','ZeroQiQi','Baosity','Huawei'
                                                      ,'Alloet','Hontinga','OME','Jotun','Yamaha')
group by brand_name
```

and the second query

```
SELECT name
,item_sold_30d
,brand_name
,category_name
,product_url
 FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT b.name,b.item_sold_30d , b.brand_name ,b.category_name, a.product_url,                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.name,b.item_sold_30d , b.brand_name ,b.category_name ORDER BY  a.product_url) as rowId
 FROM "dasync"."outputs_lazada_my"a
  INNER JOIN "catalog-my"."catalog_my_20210425"b ON b.name = a.name
  WHERE b.name like '%'||brand_name||'%' and b.brand_name =''
  ORDER BY b.item_sold_30d DESC
   ) dt
  WHERE dt.rowId = 1
  limit 10;
```

please help me to combine these 2

Comment: Sample data and required result would help.

Comment: @Serg the out put will be the same as I explained first get result from the first query then combine with the second

Comment: The first query returns the brands you specified, but the second query returns empty brands. Can the two be used together?

Comment: @meysamasadi thanks for commenting , the second one will return the names that has these brands in it for example 'HP laptop S$500' will this row will be picked because of the name contains HP

Comment: WHERE b.name like '%'||brand_name||'%' and b.brand_name ='' . That is, the names that are in the brand and the brand is empty. As a result, the product name is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries or CTEs. With subqueries it looks like:

```
SELECT name, item_sold_30d, brand_name, category_name, product_url
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT b.name, b.item_sold_30d, b.brand_name, b.category_name, a.product_url, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.name, b.item_sold_30d, b.brand_name, b.category_name ORDER BY a.product_url) AS rowId
    FROM "dasync"."outputs_lazada_my" a
    INNER JOIN "catalog-my"."catalog_my_20210425" b ON b.name = a.name
    WHERE b.brand_name = '' 
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM "catalog-my"."catalog_my_20210425"
            WHERE store_merchant_id LIKE '%lazada%'
                AND brand_name IN ('HP', 'Acer', 'VAKIND', 'Casio', 'Lenovo', 'BF1 Soul',
                                    'Sony', 'Lenovo', 'Samsung', 'Bosch', 'Xiaomi',
                                    'Panasonic', 'Dell', 'Rondaful', 'Toshiba', 'UCUC',
                                    'zanzea', 'CAMERON SINO', 'ZZOOI', 'Canon',
                                    'Philips', 'LEGO', 'Glamorousky', 'ZeroQiQi', 'Baosity', 'Huawei',
                                    'Alloet', 'Hontinga', 'OME', 'Jotun', 'Yamaha')
                AND b.name LIKE '%' || brand_name || '%'
        )
    ORDER BY b.item_sold_30d DESC
) dt
WHERE dt.rowId = 1
LIMIT 10;
```